# How to effectively utilize a VHDL module?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl

**There's a few questions in here, so bear with me, and thanks for taking the time to read this...**

I recently wrote an SPI master, and have fully simulated it to make sure it works as expected.
From here I'd like to use it in another design where I've already got a 7 segment display component set up to take the value received from an ADC on the SPI bus, however I think I've confused myself with things at this point.

I need to send a pulse with other parameters to the SPI master to initiate a transfer, and wait on a busy signal to be de-asserted before I can send anything else. **I'm not really sure how best way to implement the SPI master within the new design.**

*Would I use it in the design as a component? is there a better way?*

If it has to be a component, *is there any way I can set it up to directly output from that component to pins rather than me having to map to new inputs/outputs in the top level design?*

For example, I have SCLK, MOSI, MISO, and CS; *Can I not just have them output directly rather than having to be mapped through the top level?* Seems like it'd simplify the top level and make it less clunky.

Also, *would it be possible to set up a function to just say "Send this data over SPI and then return what's received"?*

I'm still getting my head around how to put these things together so help/examples would be greatly  appreciated. It seems like all the examples/tutorials available are based on things like using two half-adders, logic gates, etc. which only help to a point when they're so simple.

edit: Entity of my SPI Master

```
entity SPI_master is

    generic(data_width: integer := 8;
            clock_select: integer := 0);

    port(SCLK: out std_logic; 
         MOSI: out std_logic;
         MISO: in std_logic;
         CS: out std_logic;

         Mclk_in: in std_logic;
         RST: in std_logic;
         CPOL: in std_logic;
         CPHA: in integer;
         send_packet: in std_logic;
         busy: out std_logic;

         Tx_data: in std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0);
         Rx_data: out std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0));

end SPI_master;
```

Comment: It might be helpful to add the entity declaration (not the architecture) for your SPI master to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Your entity looks reasonable, though better names or comments on CPOL,CPHA would be useful!

Partial answers :

1) You CAN use it in your design as a component, but as previously mentioned, direct entity instantiation is simpler and less verbose.

2) No you can't directly output from deep in the hierarchy, and even if you could it would be a terrible idea!

Are you familiar with "Design Patterns" from C++, Ada or Java programming? If so, think of your top level design as the "Facade" pattern.

It's the only thing the external world needs to know about your design. And it will often be written as structural HDL, instantiating your other entities, and making interconnections between sub-units and connections to external ports.

There are ways to reduce the pain of these interconnections, especially across multiple layers of hierarchy, but ultimately you must break out the SPI signals to individual pins on the top level design, so that they can be connected to the correct wires on the PCB!

3) would it be possible to set up a function to just say "Send this data over SPI and then return what's received" ... not a function, no.

But certainly you can introduce a hardware wrapper to provide the rest of your design with a simple view of a complex task. For example, (assuming "send_packet" is asserted to write a byte on SPI, and "busy" goes high until the write is complete) you can create an entity taking an array of bytes and a "start" signal as inputs. Its architecture contains a process to count the bytes, outputting each in turn to SPI and waiting while "busy", and it can signal to its "caller" when done.